# Where in "Discrete Time Signal Processing" (Oppenheim et al.) can I find the scale-change theorem?

Tags: discrete-signals

I'm sorry to bother you with this question, but somehow I fail to find the corresponding passage?

Comment: Sorry but what's **scale-change** theorem? Such a name does not appear (that I remember so) in that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale-change theorem could be better known as the [scaling property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49753/intuition-behind-the-scaling-property-of-fourier-transforms) or scaling formula,  a property of the continuous Fourier transform. It is one avatar of the "invariance" properties ("scale invariance") of some kernel transformations.

It tells you about some proto-version of the Gabor-Weyl-Heisenberg limit: if you compress a signal along the  time axis, it will expand or dilate in frequency, and *vice-versa*. This is the main **duality** aspect of the time and frequency variables.

More precisely, if $s(t)\mapsto S(f)$, then $\forall \alpha \neq 0$, and $ S(f)$ is the Fourier transform, then for the compressed signal:

$$  s(\alpha t) \mapsto  \frac{1}{|\alpha|} S \left(  \frac{f}{|\alpha|}\right) $$

For discrete signals $s[n]$, not all real $\alpha$s dilations  make sense in general, because $\alpha n$ may not be a valid integer index.

Discrete equivalents exist for the time reversal ($\alpha = -1$) and integers or inverses of integers ($\alpha = k$ or $\alpha = 1/k$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$), and fractions in general, somehow corresponding to downsampling and upsampling, addressed in Chapter 4.6,  Changing the sampling rate using discrete-time processing, page 167 sq., with [a related lecture at Rice](https://archive.cnx.org/contents/5c879a76-e347-48c1-ba53-ef7e3225ec67@2/changing-sampling-rates-in-discrete-time).

A recent reference: [Generalized Rational Sampling Rate Conversion Polyphase FIR Filter](https://doi.org/10.1109/LSP.2017.2750904), IEEE Signal Processing Letters, Nov. 2017. For a more historical one, [On upsampling, downsampling, and rational sampling rate filter banks](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/r/rameshg/gopinath-updown-trans-sp1994.pdf), R. Gopinath, 1994.